# Ubuntu 20.04, force Nautilus to use SMB1, when /etc/samba does not exist?

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, samba, smb

i have Ubuntu 20.04 system and i have problems to access to an old NAS that only supports the old protocol SMB1 / NT1.

i read that i can add "client min protocol=NT1" to "/etc/samba/smb.conf".
but my installation does not have a "/etc/samba" folder installed at all.

i tried to create a folder "/etc/samba" and a file "/etc/samba/smb.conf"
with content:

```
[global]
client min protocol=NT1
```

but this will not make Nautilus working with that specific old NAS.

how can i force Nautilus to use SMB1 / NT1 protocol, when there is no samba installed and no /etc/samba/ folder exist?

PS.: i don't know if Ubuntu 20.04 initially was installed in minimal configuration and the /etc/samba wasn't configured from beginning or if the samba part was uninstalled afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

smb.conf doesn't actually come from the samba ( server ) package. It comes from samba-common since it has options that can control both client and server.

If youhave no need for a samba server on your system the best way to get smb.conf onto you system is to install smbclient:

```
sudo apt install smbclient
```

**I would suggest removing the smb.conf file you created manually before you install smbclient.**

Comment: thank you. yes, i installed smbclient and let it overriding my custom smb.conf file with the file from the package. and then i added "client min protocol=NT1" now it works.
but why can nautilus hanfle smb shares with a higher protocol with out a /etc/samba/smb.conf file but don't have the ability to switch the protocol be itself?

Comment: Nautilus uses a samba client library ( libsmbclient ) when it accesses a host. In the absence of a smb.conf it relies on the defaults which is set to SMB2. Despite it's name smb.conf is not THE samba configuration file. It is a file that has overrides of or additions to the default settings. And that is exactly how you are using it.