# Another Ubuntu 20.04 / Samba Question

Tags: 20.04, samba

Over this last weekend I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04LTS to 20.04LTS.  I'm still working out the kinks, but the biggest issue I'm trying to resolve is access 3 of my NAS devices.  These are older D-Link DNS-321 and -323, so they don't support the newer flavors of SMB.

I added the `client min protocol = NT1` entry to smb.conf, but I still can't add the shares via Files.  When trying to connect to smb://192.168.1.foo/Volume_1, I get an error message of:  "**Unable to access location - Failed to mount Windows share: Software caused connection abort.**"

However, when I use `smbclient //192.168.1.foo/Volume_1 -U user` I can log in and dir the contents.  So I am flummoxed as to why Files won't mount the share, but smbclient is very happy.

Based on the results from smbclient, I think I have smb.conf and Samba in general set up correctly, I just can't figure out why those settings aren't being passed on to Nautilus / Files.

Comment: I use the following solution to access my NAS in 20.04. First I did sudo apt-get install cifs-utils and then created the mount point (which I tthink you have done). My fstab entry is //192.168.1.foo/share-name /mount-point/share-name cifs username=foo,password=foo,rw,uid=1000,gid=500 and the drive mounts perfectly each time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04, force Nautilus to use SMB1, when /etc/samba does not exist?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270219/ubuntu-20-04-force-nautilus-to-use-smb1-when-etc-samba-does-not-exist)

Comment: Mike, not really. I have an smb.conf, and am using smbclient just fine.  What I can't figure out is why smbclient is successful at viewing the shares when Nautilus can't.  I thought Nautilus was just pulling the same info as smbclient, and displaying it graphically.

Comment: Is it just a typo in your post that you are using two different network addresses? Nautilus: `//192.168.1.foo/Volume_1` , smbclient: `//192.168.1.foo/share`

Comment: @User24601, I used your tip to mount as CIFS shares, and it worked. I did have to add a ver=1.0 to the fstab entry, but that was the only change I had to make from your original suggestion.  Thank you again.

Comment: @Morbius1, it was a typo.  Thank you for the heads up, i fixed it.

Comment: would you like me to précis that as an answer then for you accept?

Comment: @User24601, Yes, if you please.

Comment: Added comment as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following solution to access my Synology NAS in Ubuntu 20.04.1

This also works perfectly well in 18.04.5 on a different PC.

First I did `sudo apt-get install cifs-utils` and then created the mount point (which I think you have done).

My fstab entry is:

```
//192.168.1.foo/share-name /mount-point/share-name cifs username=foo,password=foo,rw,uid=1000,gid=500
```

and the drive mounts perfectly each time.

The OP mentions that he added `ver=1.0` to the fsab entry (but mine works without).